# password Successfully updated but cant use in login form any idea java?

Tags: java, database

code in update button

```
    String password = new String(oldPass.getPassword());
    String newPassword = new String(newPass.getPassword());
    String realpass = zz.getText();
    String us = z.getText();

  if(password.equals(realpass))
            {
                System.out.println("ok");
           String query = "UPDATE user SET password = '"+newPassword+"' WHERE username = '"+us+"'";

           try{
 Statement st = (Statement) con.prepareStatement(query);
      int i = st.executeUpdate(query);
      if(i!=0){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your password is successfully changed!");
      }
      else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ooopps! I guess you should call your programmer. ^^");
      }

  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
  }
```

}

code in log in

```
    Methods m = new Methods();
    String pass = new String (password.getPassword());
    String user = username.getText();



     if(m.logInUser(user, pass)==true){

form2 f = new form2();
f.setUser(user);
f.setPass(pass);
f.setVisible(true);

 this.dispose();
                }....and so on....
```

code for method log in user

```
   public boolean logInUser(String user, String pass){ //true = nakarecord na sa database login form
    try{

        String query = "Select * from user where username = ? && password = aes_encrypt('"+pass+"', 'nicanor')";
        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,user);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}//logInUser
```

it says successfully connected in sql and the database is updated but i cant see the next form that should pop up after i entered the updated password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code:

(1) **In your `update()` logic**, you are using the mix of `PreparedStatement` and `Statement` together, rather use always use `PreparedStatement` to bind the input parameters, **otherwise they (statements/queries) are prone to SQL injection attacks**.

You can refer the below code with inline comments to bind the input parameters with `PreparedStatement`:

```
    //Write the SQL query with ? to bind the parameters in PreparedStatement
    String query = "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE username = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try{
      //create the PreparedStatement object
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

      //bind the input parameters using setString()
      pstmt.setString(1, newPassword);
      pstmt.setString(2, us);

      //execute the prepare statement now
      int i = pstmt.executeUpdate(query);

      if(i!=0){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your password 
                                      is successfully changed!");
      }
      else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
              "Ooopps! I guess you should call your programmer. ^^");
      }

  } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
  } finally {
        if(pstmt != null)
              pstmt.close();
        if(con != null)
              con.close();
  }
```

Also, remember that database resources are costly and you need to `close` the resources in the `finally` block as shown above, otherwise you will end up with resource leaks.

(2) **In your `logInUser()` logic**, you are using && which is incorrect, rather in sql you need to use **AND** operator as shown below:

```
String query = "Select * from user where username = ? 
AND password = aes_encrypt('"+pass+"', 'nicanor')";
```

Comment: i tried the code but it gave me this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE username = ?' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: Did it work now ? If it works, you can upvote & accept the answer, else let me know

Comment: it doesnt it gave me this message com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionE‌​xception: No operations allowed after connection closed. and it not updating in database :(

Comment: in which method u r getting this exception ?

Comment: Open the dataabse connection before con.prepareStatement(query) line in update method